# Search for and modify a firewall rule in powershell using Get-NetFirewallRule/PortFilter/AddressFilter

Tags: powershell, sccm, windows-firewall

What I am trying to do seems simple but I need help knitting all the pieces together.

What I want to do is search all the firewall rules based on local port and protocol (i.e. 3389 TCP) then, if I find one, ensure that the RemoteAddress is set to x.x.x.x.  If I don't find one, then add it.

I can't seem to find out how to knit together Get-NetFirewallPortFilter, Get-NetFirewallAddressFilter, and Get-NetFirewallRule to do what I want.

We have a Remote Desktop Gateway and Multi-Factor Authentication and as part of compliance, all RDP connections must go through the RDGateway so that Two Factor is used.  There is a rule in place at the firewall but I want to find some way to enforce this on mass using Powershell (in an SCCM compliance item) at the Windows Firewall level too.  Sure I could do a Group Policy Objects but I want to be able to report on compliance which is why I am trying to do this via System Center Configuration Manager.

Comment: Do share some code if you can--it gives us an idea of what level help you need. If you're really lost, then start small: try to work out how to find just the rule(s) you want without worrying too much about how you are going to change them.

Comment: You might also look for rules that allow all ports from other addresses. Along with verifying that RDP is running on the expected port.

Also, Deny Rules take precedence so you can deny IP blocks.

Comment: The get-netfirewallportfilter doc has a lot of relevant examples:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netsecurity/get-netfirewallportfilter?view=win10-ps

Answer (score 0):

Piping each command to the next takes the input and filters to the end where your result showing the list of Scopes (RemoteAddress) by expanding the selected property, which you can then use to Edit your Set. Each Command shows a subset of the prior one...

Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Allow Port 3389 - RDP Access" |Get-NetFirewallAddressFilter |Select -expandproperty RemoteAddress

Comment: Thank you for answering. Please add some text to explain how your solution works.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh.  I believe this will work.  You can pipe these things both ways.  I believe it's pretty self explanatory, but it takes 2 minutes on my computer.  At least I got a progress bar.  The whatif output is actually incorrect.  That's the name, not the displayname.

EDIT:  Oh I see.  It's much faster without the first command.  I guess that's the point.  I never understood.  It's like the -filter parameter to other commands like get-childitem, that make it faster.  Get-NetfirewallPortFilter actually returns the name of the firewall rule if you look at all the properties.

```
# Get-NetFirewallRule | 
Get-NetFirewallPortFilter -Protocol TCP | 
Where LocalPort -eq 3389 | Get-NetFirewallRule | 
Set-NetFirewallRule -RemoteAddress 192.168.1.1 -WhatIf
```

Output:

```
What if: Set-NetFirewallRule DisplayName: RemoteDesktop-UserMode-In-TCP
```